# I use two libraries simultaneously to work with photos(glide and gravityView)

Tags: java, android

I use two libraries simultaneously to work with photos.

1.implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

(https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
2. compile 'co.gofynd.library:gravity-view:1.0'
(https://github.com/gofynd/gravity-view)

I want to get a photo from the Internet with the Glide library then use the 
gravity library
But the library's inputs are imageview and int drawable.
I can not get the int drawable input
my codes for the gravity library:

```
    private void setGravityMotion()
    {
       gravityView = GravityView.getInstance(this);
       if (!gravityView.deviceSupported())
       {
          return;
       } else
       {
         gravityView.setImage(imageView, R.drawable.background)
            .center();
         Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
```

What should I do instead of R.drawable.background?

Comment: You need to use image from resource folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are using supports two types of images

1. The resource int
2. Bitmap image

You are using the first type which cannot be used with `Glide`. Instead create a bitmap using the `Glide` library then load it in the library.

Your code will look like this

```
Glide
.with(getApplicationContext())
.load("https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo11w.png")
.asBitmap()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
        gravityView.setImage(imageView, resource)
    }
});
```

I believe `Glide 4.0` has a different way to get bitmap but it will still work

Answer (score 1):

Please check screen shot of drawable you need to use.

[image]

```
private void setGravityMotion()
    {
       gravityView = GravityView.getInstance(this);
       if (!gravityView.deviceSupported())
       {
          return;
       } else
       {
         gravityView.setImage(imageView, R.drawable.ic_3d)
            .center();
         Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use probably like this:

```
ViewTarget<ImageView, Bitmap> viewTarget =  Glide.with(activity)
                                                 .asBitmap()
                                                 .load("URL")
                                                 .into(imageView);
Drawable drawable = viewTarget.getView().getDrawable(); // Declare according your scope 


private void setGravityMotion() {
   gravityView = GravityView.getInstance(this);
   if (!gravityView.deviceSupported())
   {
      return;
   } else
   {
     gravityView.setImage(imageView, drawable/*Place here*/)
        .center();
     Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

I have not tested it, Hope it works.